# Realization of braiding on infinite dimensional vector space via Yetter-Drinfeld structure over Hopf algebra

Tags: hopf-algebras

In one article I found the following statement

> Let $V$ be finite dimensional vector space. A braiding $\Psi$ on $V$ can be realized via Yetter-Drinfeld structure over a Hopf algebra with invertible antipode iff $\Psi$ is biinvertible.

Is it true in general, i.e. if $V$ is infinite dimensional vector space ?